# Power Bi function issue

Tags: powerbi

Could someone please assist with a formula to extract Top AOM in a card for me? I created a card for Top Area with the following formula which appears to work fine

```
Top Area =
  CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE('F E  Data'[Area]),
    topn(2, all('F E  Data'[Area]), [%Comp], DESC)
  )
```

When I attempt to use the same formula for top AOM, the card comes back blank. I used the following formula,

```
Top Area = 
  CALCULATE(
    SELECTEDVALUE('F E  Data'[AOM]),
    topn(2, all('F E  Data'[AOM]), [%Comp], DESC)
  )
```

I am attempting for my dashboard to indicate the top performing AOM(PHX in this case) based off of the highest %Comp for the day.

Picture enclosed below. Please let me know if you require any more detail and thank you all for your support!
[Power Bi example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qzn6R.jpg)
I have tried modifying the code different ways but am still unable to display the AOM i nthe card.

Answer (score 0):

Why the `2` in the `TOPN` ?
Try:

```
Top AOM = 
  CALCULATE(
    MAX('F E  Data'[AOM]),
    TOPN(1, all('F E  Data'[AOM]), [%Comp], DESC)
  )
```